# Why am I getting duplicate ghost points (features), i.e., one point in the feature class but two points?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, point, arcgis-9.3, features, error

When editing some of the attributes in a point feature class in ArcMap 9.3, duplicate labels started showing up.  When I click on the point, I discovered that the point has duplicated itself BUT there is only one line in the feature class.  If I highlight the row (the feature), I find that there are two points in one row - almost like a ghost point.  I can't get rid of them and it seems that it gets worse (more duplicate ghost points) the more I edit.  If I select all in the attribute table, the number selected is the correct number but the table adds the ghost points to the total number of records.  Confussed?  So am I.  Tried stop editing and deleting version and restarting -- starts back at normal and then starts replicating ghost points as I edit.

Thoughts????
Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Do you have any custom editing tools? You mentioned versioning so this must be on SDE. What geometry storage option does your feature class use (SDE Binary, ST_Geometry, etc.)? Maybe you or your database administrator can look at the tables on the back end to get an idea of what's happening when you make an edit and the problem crops up.

Answer (score 1):

[image: label classes]
If you have set up labeling with **"define classes of features..."** and have more than one class that does not exclude the other, you will see this issue.

You should define your classes with an sql that eliminates objects from the other classes. Or use the get classes button which will get the classses you have defined in your symbology and build a seperate sql for each.
I do recommend using this mehod to learn how it works, but i normally build my own classes and define the sql by hand.

If this is not the case (upon re-read of your problem) it might be... 
that you have a definition query setup in your layer, and have no symbology for the feature you are creating.

Remove any definition queries and turn on the "all other values" section in your symbology.

Comment: THanks, I will look at that... although if it were just labeling I could understand it.  It is that if I select one feature (point) there are actually 2 there but only one in the attribute table.  That is why I said it was a ghost and the number of the ghost points change when I edit the attributes - both the unedited and edited are present if I select the point as if they are both caught in the delta tables somehow.  Contacting ESRI as well.

Answer (score 1):

This could happen if a single feature class is added in arcmap as two layers in the table of contents(a remote possibility). Did you try to add the feature classes to a blank Mxd?